# 3 Channel image access using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm having a  2D Vector called Mat with values from 0 to 255 that I'm assigning to an IPLIMAGE like what is follow:

```
 IplImage *A=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
 for (int i=0;i<640;i++)
{
 for (j...)
 {
    A->imageData[i*640+j]=Mat[i][j]
 }
}
```

But what about if  i m having 3 2D vectors Mat1, Mat2, Mat3 and an IPLIMAGE whose number of channels is equal to 3:

```
IplImage *A=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
```

I thought that I could do it channel by channel and merge them all at the end, but I really believe it's not the optimal solution.

Any idea how to access to imageData of the 3 channels in that case?

Comment: Why are you using old C API? This would be much easier with C++ Mat class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that you can avoid writing the first code if `Mat` is aligned, by directly assigning the `imageData` struct member of `IplImage`. You'll have to use `cvCreateImageHeader` instead of `cvCreateImage` to avoid allocating data for the image. More info about the struct can be found [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#iplimage).

Second, regarding your question - it is possible to do that by creating three images by the technique I mentioned earlier, and then using `cvMerge` to produce the final image. More information [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#merge).

In general, I recommend you to migrate to the C++ interface of OpenCV, which uses `cv::Mat` instead of the old `IplImage` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at OpenCV tutorial for C++ API, there is example for working with Mat.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-iterator-safe-method

There are presented 3 ways to access 3 channel image.